# How to allow Java plug-ins by default in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, java

On a certain page, I get a yellow bar like the one shown here:
http://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml

The problem is, I can't click on "Run this time" or either "Always run on this site", because a pop-up window is warning me about an error which very likely stems from the lack of Java. The very moment I close said dialog, the yellow bar disappears as the address is redirected. Yeah I've tried to outrun it. No good.

So I'm kind of stuck here since "java" wasn't found in the Chrome settings. Is there a way to have Java plug-ins enabled by default? Or adding a page to the allowed list *before* entering it?

Comment: Java is now gone: http://superuser.com/q/902575/78897

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always allow plugins in Google Chrome by navigating to `chrome://plugins` and selecting the *Always allowed* checkbox next to the relevant plugin.

> [image: chrome://plugins]