# How to re-enable Java plugin on Google Chrome 42 on Windows

Tags: google-chrome, java, java-applet, browser-plugin

As stated in [NPAPI deprecation: developer guide](https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation):

> In April 2015 (Chrome 42) NPAPI support will be disabled by default in
>   Chrome and we will unpublish extensions requiring NPAPI plugins from
>   the Chrome Web Store. All NPAPI plugins will appear as if they are not
>   installed, as they will not appear in the navigator.plugins list nor
>   will they be instantiated (even as a placeholder). Although plugin
>   vendors are working hard to move to alternate technologies, a small
>   number of users still rely on plugins that haven’t completed the
>   transition yet. We will provide an override for advanced users (via
>   chrome://flags/#enable-npapi) and enterprises (via Enterprise Policy)
>   to temporarily re-enable NPAPI (via the page action UI) while they
>   wait for mission-critical plugins to make the transition. In addition,
>   setting any of the plugin Enterprise policies (e.g. EnabledPlugins,
>   PluginsAllowedForUrls) will temporarily re-enable NPAPI.

So, April came and Google Chrome disabled NPAPI plugins, including Java.

How to re-enable them on Windows machines?

Comment: @Ramhound, The other question if focused on Mac OS X. Could you review the duplication?

Comment: Not a duplicate. That question asks why Java was disabled. This asks how to enable it anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## NOTE

### Java  no longer works in Chrome. None of the previous techniques/hacks (see [revision](https://superuser.com/revisions/902576/4)) will work.

Comment: None of these work with Chrome 46 anymore... What now?

Comment: Sadly, there is no alternative yet. As a enterprise user, I'll have to change browsers to use some company applications.

Comment: Run Chromium 41, which has out-of-the-box NPAPI support, with no enable/disable flag. See this post: 
https://superuser.com/questions/988243/where-to-download-the-last-chrome-version-with-java-npapi-support

Comment: @kmiklas One should absolutely not use an old version of chrome, as it contain a lot of security breaches already addressed on newer versions. A lot of these security breaches don't rely on the user downloading anything. They can infect your computer by just browsing to a page.

Comment: @motobói yes, I know... we all know. Given the choice, we would have it another way. Unfortunately there are legacy applications out there which require NPAPI, so we don't have much choice in the matter.