# Chrome prompts to install silverlight even though it's already installed

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, silverlight

On Windows XP box, SL5 was working in Chrome and IE8. Then, today, chrome prompts to install SL. Upon doing so, the SL install program says that the same version of SL is already installed.  Chrome:plugins does not show silverlight (but it should!).  IE8 works fine as does visual studio 2010.

Since the chrome plugin does not show up as a chrome plugin, I suspect some sort of corruption in chrome setup. But, a re-install of chrome did not fix the problem.

I tried in this order:

1. Uninstall silverlight via control panel
2. then re-install
3. uninstall chrome then re-install
4. do a system restore to 2 days ago when everything worked

The system restore was interesting in that it caused even more problems. IE would load a SL site like it was going to work (the % loading widget showed up) but the page was blank.  Chrome crashed with a Misrosoft "we're sorry dialog". An attempt to uninstall chrome did the same - so I undid the restore point and got it back to the original problem.

What should I do next?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Chrome?  Chrome 42 has basically discontinued support for the Silverlight extension.  You can enable it again using the method described in this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/902575/how-to-re-enable-java-plugin-on-google-chrome-42)

Comment: Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 m

Comment: Follow the directions I provided to enable the NPAPI extension in question.

Comment: That worked!  Amazing.  What are they thinking?  Now I wait for the support calls to come in. Oh Joy.

Comment: NPAPI extensions pose a huge security risk.  By the end of 2015 Chrome will not be able to use NPAPI extensions.  Of course Chrome also will stop supporting Windows XP by the end of 2015.  **Plan accordingly.**

Comment: Why the downvote for this question?

SIlverlight is(was) a mature technology used in possibly hundreds of thousands of business applications. For Google/Chrome to so cavalierly disable it shows an immense amount of bad form and bad decision making. 

This action is clearly a snub to Microsoft, but Chrome should think long and hard about such actions because such actions don't just affect Microsoft--they affect Microsoft's business clients and partners. Such childish actions should have ended at the schoolyard.